# How to get Oracle error message from error number?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm writing a C# application that executes some functions stored in packages in oracle database. Unfortunately, I don't have access and I can not change the structure of these functions...

The functions are made such that, when the operation went good, they return 0, otherwise they return the oracle error code number.

Of course if I search for these codes **(ORA-xxxxx)** in the internet I can know what went wrong but I would like to display, in case of an error, a message to the user to understand the error instead of just showing the error number.

Does anyone know to get the oracle error message associated with the error number ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_error_msg(f_code IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN sqlerrm(-f_code); 
END;

select get_error_msg(100) from dual;
```